# What is the expected area of the implied triangle formed by bending a unit length at a right angle at a beta distributed point?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

This is similar to the question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466154/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-hypotenuse-formed-by-bending-a-unit-length-ra) but instead of the point being uniformly distributed we choose it based on a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). Simulations show a simple relationship between the area and $\alpha=\beta$, so I am wondering if there is a closed form here that can be derived.

[image]

In the case $\alpha=\beta=1$ we have the [special case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466154/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-hypotenuse-formed-by-bending-a-unit-length-ra) of the point being uniformly distributed.

In the case of $\alpha=\beta$ I believe the integral involved takes the form:

$$\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\alpha-1}x(1-x)dx = \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\alpha)}x^{\alpha}(1-x)^{\alpha}dx$$

In the more complicated case of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ different the integral becomes:

$$\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}x(1-x)dx = \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}x^{\alpha}(1-x)^{\beta}dx$$

Comment: Just notice that $\int_0^1 x^\alpha (1-x)^{\beta}dx=B(\alpha+1,\beta+1)$ and simplify it using the relationship with the gamma function.

Comment: Something is wrong with your simulations. The largest area one can get is $1/8$...

Comment: @d.k.o. Yes thank you, good catch. I accidentally posted the simulation of the expected hypotenuse. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{\alpha}(1-x)^{\beta}}{2B(\alpha,\beta)}\,dx=\frac{B(\alpha+1,\beta+1)}{2B(\alpha,\beta)}=\frac{\alpha\beta}{2(\alpha+\beta+1)(\alpha+\beta)}.
$$
As expected $A(\alpha,\alpha)\to 1/8$ as $\alpha\to\infty$.